# I want to change the display of my months in fullcalender

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want to change the display names of my months in full calendar like now they showing "January" and I want to "Jan" like for all months can anyone suggest I am that stuck in a very long time.

Comment: which language you are using ..? in java `EEE` is used to show full calendar and try using `EE` for short name.

Comment: @AmolBais fullCalendar (as per the tag description) is a JavaScript-based browser library. Nothing to do with Java EE. https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: @AmolBais P.S. A friendly tip: I just visited your profile page. In your description, you write that you are "self centered". In normal English usage this is not a good thing. See the definition at https://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-centered - whilst it _can_ mean "independent, self-sufficient", most English speakers will not normally use it like that. The overwhelmingly most common meaning is "selfish". I just point this out so that you might consider changing your profile! :-)

Comment: @SolailKhan you need to use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/columnHeaderFormat to configure the names.

Comment: @ADyson thank you so much for correction, it was written long back ago. i have change it now.

Comment: Thank You @ADyson this doc is working for me and I have resolved my issue.